# Логическая ошибка в написании функции postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Написал функцию первичное значение которой добавить в таблицу новую строку, если  параметр функции in_id = 0. Или заменить старую строку, если in_id равен уже существующему id в таблице. 
Изначально проблемы была в том, что конфликт не создавался, если не было строки с id = 0, и тогда просто добавлялась новая строка с таким id. Я решил сделать конфликт в любом случае и в качестве действий в результате конфликта решил ставить id дефолтным, когда in_id равен 0. 
По такой логике конфликт создается в любом случае, строка с id = 0 не должна создаваться. и получается, что если in_id = 0, то создается новая строка с дефолтным id, в противном случае строка перезаписывается с ранее указанными значениями VALUES.
 
Но почему то при in_id = 0 все равно создается строка с нулевым id, а в противном случае вообще ничего не происходит. В чем у меня ошибка и как ее испрвить?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_test( 
    in_id integer, 
    in_author text, 
    in_summary text, 
    in_story text, 
    in_topic text, 
    in_date date 
) 

RETURNS SETOF private.start_model 
AS 
$$ 
    INSERT INTO private.start_model( 
        id,
        author, 
        summary, 
        story, 
        topic, 
        date 
    ) VALUES(
        in_id,
        in_author, 
        in_summary, 
        in_story, 
        in_topic, 
        in_date 
    ) 
    ON CONFLICT( id )

    WHERE true

    DO UPDATE 
        SET 
            id = default 
                where in_id = 0         
    RETURNING *;
$$ 

LANGUAGE SQL 
VOLATILE 
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Comment: *Написал функцию первичное значение которой добавить в таблицу новую строку, если параметр функции in_id = 0.* Для решения этой задачи ON CONFLICT непригоден. И достаточно вульгарного `CASE WHEN in_id != 0 THEN in_id END` в VALUES(). Если он ноль, он заменится на NULL, что вызовет генератор.

Comment: @Akina, окей, однако же мне хотелось бы услышать почему он не является пригодным, если не трудно объяснить. просто не пойму никак почему это не работает

Comment: *не пойму никак почему это не работает* Проследите, что и как выполняется, если: 1) in_id = 0; 2) in_id = 1, причём id = 1 уже имеется; 3) in_id = 1, причём id = 1 отсутствует. PS. Зачем Вы вообще используете WHERE? PPS. Обновление конфликтного выражения вообще-то недопустимо (потенциальный повторный конфликт).

Comment: @Akina, я не знал как избежать создания новой строки с id = 0. ее не было изначально и быть не должно.  а если строки с id = 0 не было, то и конфликта не могло существовать при in_id = 0, поэтому создавалась новая не нужная мне строка. я надеялся устранить это путем WHERE true

Comment: *я не знал как избежать создания новой строки с id = 0. ее не было изначально и быть не должно* Это делается с помощью CHECK CONSTRAINT.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за наводку, я все таки разобрался и код работает как нужно было, немного переписал условие в VALUES() и заработало

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было избавиться от WHERE true. В VALUES() для id прописать условие, согласно которому id присваивается дефолтное значение `nextval('имя_схемы.имя_таблицы_столбец_seq')`  при in_id = 0. В противном случае все остается как есть.
 
На случай конфликта в DO UPDATE передаются нужные значения для строки и она перезаписывается.